# How can I set the height of a relative positioned element inside absolute positioned element?

Tags: html, css, height

I have something like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcabnettek/qfkzz/)

```
<div id="foo">
  <div>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>


 #foo {
   position: absolute;
   min-height: 300px;
   width: 400px;
 }

 #foo > div {
   position:relative;
 }

 .header, .footer {
   min-height: 30px;
 }
```

How can I make '#foo > div' take up the 300px of height set on #foo? I want to pin '.footer' to the bottom of '#foo > div' as well. '.main' should fill the remainder of the space even if it's empty and become scrollable when it's content warrants it.

I've struggled with this for a few hours so now time to ask the gurus. Any help with fiddles would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: class="fotter" != #footer

Comment: I believe this is what you're after http://code.google.com/p/cleanstickyfooter/

Comment: you cannot, unless div is absolute too and you size it with coordinates: top,right,bottom,left

Comment: You need to say something about the height of the header and footer, otherwise, there are not enough constraints to write useful code. Also, what is the purpose of the `#foo > div`? Also what is the height of `#foo`? If you want to keep all these specs open ended, then you will need a jQuery/JavaScript assisted solution which may be beyond the scope of answering a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/V2gdj/4/

Using the following CSS;

```
div {
    border: 1px solid gray;    
}

#foo {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
}

#foo > div {
    position: relative;
    height: inherit;
}

.header, .footer {
    height: 30px;
}
.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Explanation pending on your comments.

Comment: This seems to work nicely. Thanks man. Thank you for working through my typos and bad syntax as well. I was in a bit of a hurry when I posted.

Comment: Excellent! It was a stab in the dark & delighted that it helps.  All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is referencing ID's, but your divs have classes, not ID's. Plus, you have a typo in class="fotter"

Comment: Corrected. I apologize. I was in a bit of a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a few errors to tidy up. In your HTML you call it `fotter`, but in the CSS it is `footer`. Secondly, in the HTML you have you divs with classes assigned, but in the CSS you are selecting IDs. Change one to the other and you're on the right track.

To make the footer stick to the bottom you could try this in your CSS:

```
.main {min-height: 240px;}
```

Here's a fiddle to see if it's what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/Jzq2Q/

Best of luck.